# Не могу разобраться с редактированием XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Никак не могу понять, как открыть файл, отредактировать и сохранить.
Вот например как изначально выглядит файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что мне надо сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит просто, но у меня ничего не получается

Comment: Вручную или программно?

Comment: С помощью python

Comment: Но как насчет XSLT?

Comment: Эта задача не для Python. Вам просто нужно запустить XSLT-преобразование из Python.

Comment: с помощью пайтон невозможно открыть, добавить теги и сохранить xml?

Comment: Например с тем же excel там всё просто... Можно открыть фаил, добавить в нужную ячейку что хочешь и тп... как тут то просто добавить позицию?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не объясняет всю логику, которая должна быть применена к вашему большому XML-файлу.

Comment: Да логика простая... к существующему файлу добавить новый тег pos и в тег pos добавить еще два тега title и price, с соответствующим текстом. С помощью и python и, например, библиотеки xml.etree.ElementTree как можно такое сделать?
фаил например называется "test.xml"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python

Comment: Пример нужно добавлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример модификации xml файла:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

b_el = root.find('./b')
c_el = ET.SubElement(b_el, 'c')
c_el.text = 'hi'
b_el.append(c_el)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Добавляет в `b` еще один элемент `c`:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>hello</c>
    </b>
</a>
```